# vite stuck at npm run build with docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, vite

this is a weird issue im facing
im using a docker container on my project [Mug](https://github.com/MicheleAwada/mug)

and when i run the docker compose and build the containers all is fine except for the frontend and it infinately hangs saying

```
[frontend_static 6/6] RUN npm run build                                                  321.1s
frontend@0.0.0 build
vite build
vite v4.5.1 building for production...
transforming...
```

but the thing is the repo on my machine and the vps are exactly the same

however the error is only occuring in the vps

which like contridicts the whole purpose of docker

ps another weird fact is i thought it could be due to when docker compose is building perhaps my vps small ram amount cannot handle building in docker AND doing the npm run build

however thats simply not true and the top command shows the node proccess is taking only 60% of ram and like 40% of cpu

(another note that changing RUN npm run build to CMD ["npm", "run", "build"]) is not changing anything
except i get a handy error message

```
mug_frontend_static  | transforming...
mug_frontend_static  | npm ERR! path /frontend
mug_frontend_static  | npm ERR! command failed
mug_frontend_static  | npm ERR! signal SIGKILL
mug_frontend_static  | npm ERR! command sh -c vite build
mug_frontend_static  |
mug_frontend_static  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /root/.npm/_logs/2023-12-26T08_56_38_385Z-debug-0.log
```

anyways i will provide my code here

//frontend/Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /frontend

COPY . .

RUN npm install -g vite@latest
RUN npm install

RUN npm run build
```

//docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  frontend_static:
    container_name: mug_frontend_static
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - mug_frontend_static:/frontend/dist
  backend:
    container_name: mug_backend
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./backend/mug/.env
    expose:
      - 8080
    command: gunicorn mug.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 --log-level debug
    volumes:
      - mug_static:/app/static
      - mug_media:/app/media
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - internal
  postgres:
    image: postgres:alpine
    container_name: mug_postgres
    volumes:
      - mug_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - ./backend/mug/db.env
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: Mug
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
    networks:
      - internal
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: mug_nginx
    expose:
      - 80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - mug_frontend_static:/frontend/dist
      - mug_static:/static
      - mug_media:/media
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mug.rule=(Host(`mug.micheleawada.com`) || Host(`backend.mug.micheleawada.com`))"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mug.entrypoints=websecure"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mug.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mug.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
    networks:
      - internal
      - traefikproxy

volumes:
  mug_postgres_data:
  mug_media:
  mug_static:
  mug_frontend_static:

networks:
  internal:
  traefikproxy:
    name: traefikproxy
    external: true
```

//frontend/vite.config.js

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
plugins: [react()],
build: {
watch: false,
> >         },
> > });
```

// frontend/package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-oauth/google": "^0.12.1",
    "axios": "^1.6.0",
    "flowbite-react": "^0.6.4",
    "hamburger-react": "^2.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "react-oauth": "^0.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.17.0",
    "universal-cookie": "^6.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.31",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.5",
    "vite": "^4.5.1"
  }
}
```

//package-lock.json is too long

Comment: Do you need to rebuild the image on the deployment system?  Can you build the image locally (or in a CI environment), push it to a registry, and run the image on the remote system without rebuilding it?

Comment: Have you found a solution? Running into the same problem when building a container with Bitbucket pipelines